# Executor service in executor service?

Tags: java, multithreading, lucene, indexing, executorservice

In document import method, I work with large number of files. Each file size can also 100mb-200mb. I want to use threading in asynchronously. In for loop, each file is processed and then indexed(lucene). This operation is very cost and time useless in real time. Total operation must not stop.

General structure of import method is given below:

```
public void docImport()
{
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
  for(final File file : fileList)
  {
    //Do some works...
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           zipFile(file); //Each zipped file has diff name and same directory.
           indexFile(file); //Each file is indexed same directory.
        }
    });
  }
  executor.shutdown();
}
```

General structure of indexFile method :

```
public void indexFile()
{
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  IndexWriter writer = null;
  Directory dir = .....;
  Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_VERSION);
  IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
  iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(200);   
  iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
  writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
  Document lucenedoc = new Document();
  lucenedoc.add(..);

  if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE) {
    writer.addDocument(lucenedoc);
  } else {
    writer.updateDocument(new Term(PATH, innerPath), lucenedoc);
  }
  executor.shutdown();
}
```

My question is :

while docImport method working, 5 threads read files and each of thread is trying to index files to same lucene index file.
So error occured some intervals : "org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\lucene\index\write.lock"

For example, sometimes 30 file is getting indexed in 100 files. Others is not indexed because of error.

How can I resolve this error? How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting this error when you attempt to open an `IndexWriter` when there is already a writer open on the index.

In addition to that issue, opening a new `IndexWriter` is a *very expensive* operation.  Even if you were to get it working (say synchronizing a block which opens, uses and then closes the `IndexWriter`), this would likely be quite slow.

Instead, open one `IndexWriter`, keep it open, and share it across each of the threads.

Comment: There is two classes. One of them includes docImport method, the other one includes indexFile method. indexFile method has own IndexWriter and ExecuterService. docImport method has own ExecuterService which has more threads too. As a result, how can I have one IndexWriter? In docImport, in the for loop, it calls indexFile method immeditially so IndexWriter is created every loop time.

Comment: Rewrite it.  Pass the IndexWriter into the `indexFile` method, or draw if from a common space, something like that.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon but it couldnt be successfull for me. So I changed my mind about this situation.